# comparing and interpreting two time counters

Tags: c, performance, timestamp

I have two counters that denote time.One of them is a 64-bit counter which should be interpreted as follows.

1) Most significant 32 bits indicate the number of seconds since a fixed point in time

2) Lower 32 bits indicate a fraction of a second.

I don't know how to interpret the other 48 bit counter.?

What I do know is this.

```
What COUNTER 1 increased by 508032,COUNTER 2 increased by 5914.

Meaning COUNTER1 (time 2 - time 1) = 508032
```

during that time

```
COUNTER2 (time 2 - time 1) = 5914.
```

I need a formula to figure out how to interpret the resolution of COUNTER2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counter 2 increments 50 million times per second.

5914/(508032/2^32) ~= 50 million

To put it in words: Counter 1 increments 2^32 times per second. So if it increments 508,032 times, that's 1/8454 of a second. In that time, counter 2 incremented 5,914 times. So it would increment 5,914*8,454 times in a full second. That's so close to 50 million (49.997 million) that it's almost certain counter 2's resolution is intended to be 50 million counts per second.

Comment: How did you come up with 2^32?

Comment: You said, "Lower 32 bits indicate a fraction of a second." I'm presuming you meant the full range of values is used. If not, we have insufficient information to answer.

Comment: what is 4 lower bits are disabled?

Comment: @liv2hak That means the counter doesn't have full resolution, but that doesn't affect its rate. Whether a clock goes from 6:01 to 6:02 to 6:03 or from 6:00 to 6:05 to 6:10, there's still an hour between 6:00 and 7:00.

Comment: so What you are saying is the crystal that is used has a frequencey of 50MHz?

Comment: @liv2hak I couldn't say without knowing more about the implementation of the counter. It may, for example, have a frequency of 12.5 MHz and increment by four each time.